# Restrict users to sftp access only

Tags: ssh, sftp, privileges

I want to jail a group of users with access only to a `/var/www/mysitename.com` pattern of directory via `sftp` alone.  I do not want to provide shell access either.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
Match Group group-name
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/mysitename.com
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

From the manpage:

```
ChrootDirectory
         Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
         authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-
         owned directories that are not writable by any other user or
         group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory
         to the user's home directory. [...]

 ForceCommand
         Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
         ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if
         present.  [...] Specifying a command of “internal-sftp” will 
         force the use of an in-process sftp server that requires no 
         support files when used with ChrootDirectory.
```

These conditions require that:

1. Every directory in the path `/var/www/mysitename.com` must be owned by root, and not writable by others or root.
2. All the users in this group have home directory `/` (root), or the `chroot` will fail.

Alternately, you can set `ChrootDirectory` to `/var/www`, and set the home directories of all these users to `/mysitename.com`.

Relevant reading:

- [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) entry.