# Is it possible to have different ssh keys for ssh login and sftp on the same ubuntu user

Tags: permissions, ssh, login, sftp

Is it possible to have different ssh keys for ssh login and sftp on the same ubuntu user, I've tried a lot of things until now and I was not successful, through chatGPT,i tried searching on google but could not find anything, my use case is that a have some services that I give online, and i want the user to only have access to the SFTP, but not the ssh login with that key.

Is there a workaround

Comment: The usual way to do that would be to match the *user* or *group* rather than the key - see for example [Restrict users to sftp access only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534675/restrict-users-to-sftp-access-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up this in ssh's `authorized_keys`.

According to manual

```
# Forced command, disable PTY and all forwarding
restrict,command="dump /home" ssh-rsa ...
```

So the same login with different keys will get different level of access. I can't help with exact command for that though.

**Anyway, proper way for that is to use different users and according configs in sshd.**

Comment: Thanks, I ended up setting different users for their respective requirements, as I think what I wanted to achieve was not possible.